# NSDate Returning nil

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

basically I am trying to store todays date but every time I try to do that NSDate returns nil to me

```
self.calendarView.selectedDate = [NSDate date];
```

I am new to objective-c so maybe I am doing something wrong here but it seems fairly straight forward.

Comment: How are you testing the value? Have you tried declaring a variable and storing the value of [NSDate date] and confirming that it is actually null with the debugger or a log statement?

Comment: `calendarView` is `nil`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[NSDate date]` will return a correct date. Check if your `self.calendarView` is not nil at this point by doing:

```
NSLog(@"calendar: %@", self.calendarView);
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSLog(@"now: %@", now);
self.calendarView.selectedDate = now;
```